# How to add an array (double) as a field to a struct variable?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a structure variable and want to add a field and fill the row with the values of an array (double).
The following code works but isn't very nice. Is there a more elegant way to add a field including values without the use of the mat2cell function or a for loop?

```
field1 = 1:10
field2 = 4:13
%create struct with field 'start' with 10 values
A = struct('start',mat2cell(field1,1,ones(1,numel(field1))))
%transform field2 to cell 
temp = mat2cell(field2,1,ones([numel(field2),1]));
%add field 'end' with 10 values
[A(1:numel(field2)).end] = temp{:};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) rather than `mat2cell` which will (by default) place each element in it's own cell. Unfortunately, you will still need a temporary variable.

```
A = struct('start', num2cell(field1));
tmp = num2cell(field2);
[A.end] = tmp{:};
```

Answer (score 1):

Download "catstruct":
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842-catstruct

```
clear
field1 = 1:10;
field2 = 4:13;
A = struct('start',num2cell(field1));
A = catstruct(A, struct('end',num2cell(field2)));
```

For performance you better use single field that contain array:

```
clear
field1 = 1:10;
field2 = 4:13;
A=[];
A.start = field1;
A.end = field2;
```